# PHP XMLReader - accessing ELEMENT constant but getting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM error

Tags: php, xmlreader, libxml2, parse-error

Got a server running: php 5.2.17, libxml 2.7.8 with XMLReader enabled.

The problem is, it's complaining about parse error with  T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM when I try $xmlReader::ELEMENT.

Is there any specific version that this behavior was introduced? as it seems to work fine on my offline 5.3.6 server...

```
    $xmlReader = new XMLReader;
    if (!$xmlReader->open('file.xml', null, 1<<19)){
        throw new Exception('Unable to read file',1);
    }

    # Go down to WEBRESOURCES node level
    while ($xmlReader::ELEMENT){ // This is what it throws the parse error for
        if ($xmlReader->name == "blahblah"){
            break;
        }
        $xmlReader->read();
    }
```

Thanks, Dom

Answer (score 3):

Use the name of the class instead of the instance.
`XMLReader::ELEMENT`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I've had a little look around and it seems that what I was trying is only >5.3. Is there anywhere I can read into this? Thanks :)

Comment: @Dominic http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 1):

I think your `while`-loop should look like

```
while ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) { 
    if ($xmlReader->name == "blahblah"){
        break;
    }
    $xmlReader->read();
}
```